# can't make a slug doesn't work in my routes file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I was trying to make a page with a slug from database. But it doesn't work how i am doing. I don't what I have to do. Can anyone help me?

My routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/add-album', 'AlbumController@index');
Route::post('/admin/add-album/add', 'AlbumController@store');
Route::get('/admin/show-albums', 'AlbumController@show');
Route::get('/admin/show-albums/{slug}', 'AlbumController@edit');
```

Where the slug come from:

```
 @foreach($albums as $row)
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{ URL::asset('images/' . $row->album_profile_picture) }}"></td>
                <td>{{ $row->album_name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/admin/delete/{{ $row->album_slug }}" method="post">
                        <a href="/admin/show/{{ $row->album_slug }}" class="btn btn-primary">Show</a>
                        <a href="/admin/edit/{{ $row->album_slug }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes in your blade file do not match up with the routes in your routes file. Change your HREFs in your HTML to match the following:

`<a href="/admin/show-albums/{{ $row->album_slug }}"`